# React / How to assign a variable to a classname property

Tags: reactjs

Hello

In the following code I have tried to assign the variable `classNameDiv` to a classname, but it doesn't work. Strangely double curly brackets works for the style property just below

```js
return (
  <div className="item" key={i}>
    <img src={`./images/${myjson.images[index].name}`} alt="" />
    <div className="allBoxes">
      {myjson.images[index].palette.map((index2, j) => {
        const b = myjson.images[index].palette[j]
        const classNameDiv = "colorBox";
        if (RefArrayPalette[index][j] === 1) {
          classNameDiv = "colorBox2";//_________________first here___________
        }
        return (
          <div
            key={j}
            //className="colorBox"
            className={{classNameDiv}}  //____________________then here_____________
            style={{ backgroundColor: index2 }}
            onClick={calculateNewList}
          />
        )
      }, (i, index))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example className is a `const` so it not reassignable, you should use `let`

div `className` props is expected to be a string

`className={{classNameDiv}}` actually mean you are passing the object `{ classNameDiv: classNameDiv }` as `className` prop

What you should do is `className={classNameDiv}`

Answer (score 0):

The `className` property expects a *string*, but you're passing it an *object*:

```
className={{classNameDiv}}
```

Just pass it the string value:

```
className={classNameDiv}
```

> Strangely double curly brackets works for the style property just below

Because the `style` property expects an object.  It's not really "double curly braces", it's an object literal (which uses curly braces) inside of a JSX property (which uses curly braces).